# Unable to push on beanstalk master

Tags: git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, beanstalk-svn

I am using windows git bash, when i run the command 
git push beanstalk master

I got the following error,

```
Connected to host `XXXXXX.beanstalkapp.com port 22:` bad file number 

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are either behind a proxy that is not able to forward the key or a firewall is not allowing outgoing port 22 ( the port used by SSH by default ) access. Try fixing that or use alternate protocol like https for pushing.

Answer (score 1):

It can mean some kind of network issue with ssh (at work, for instance, any outgoing ssh request through port 22 is strictly forbidden).
But I don't think [beanstalkapp](http://beanstalkapp.com/) supports [smart http](https://github.com/blog/642-smart-http-support) like GitHub does, so that means no https for you either.
You might try some "[workaround](http://help.github.com/firewalls-and-proxies/)", like [using port 443 (SSL) for your SSH requests](http://blog.codeslower.com/2008/8/Using-PuTTY-and-SSL-to-securely-access-GitHub-repositories-via-SSH), but make sure you aren't circumventing any enterprise security policy.